# Sitecore glass editable cannot convert lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

I'm using Sitecore 7.5, MVC 5.2 and Glass Mapper 3.2.

When using Editable() in the renderings, the error below is shown in visual studio even though it renders properly when using the site and/or the page editor. Am I missing a reference or something?

**Error:** 
"Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' because it is not a delegate type"

**View**

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation

@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<Air.SitecoreModels.Metadata>

@*<h1>@Model.Item.Name </h1>*@

<h2>@Editable(x => x.BrowserTitle)</h2>
```

**Model** (auto generated with TDS)

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId=IMetadataConstants.TemplateIdString )] //, Cachable = true 
public partial interface IMetadata : IGlassBase 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The BrowserTitle field.
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
    /// <para>Field ID: 82cb07ca-0f04-442e-9a42-641d71540b35</para>
    /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
    /// </summary>
    [SitecoreField(IMetadataConstants.BrowserTitleFieldName)]
    string BrowserTitle  {get; set;}

                /// <summary>
    /// The PageTitle field.
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
    /// <para>Field ID: 462e2170-1157-4e9d-92dc-0d5da2956c44</para>
    /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
    /// </summary>
    [SitecoreField(IMetadataConstants.PageTitleFieldName)]
    string PageTitle  {get; set;}

}


[SitecoreType(TemplateId=IMetadataConstants.TemplateIdString, AutoMap=true)] //, Cachable = true
public partial class Metadata  : GlassBase, IMetadata 
{

    /// <summary>
    /// The BrowserTitle field.
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
    /// <para>Field ID: 82cb07ca-0f04-442e-9a42-641d71540b35</para>
    /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
    [SitecoreField(IMetadataConstants.BrowserTitleFieldName)]
    public virtual string BrowserTitle  {get; set;}

            /// <summary>
    /// The PageTitle field.
    /// <para></para>
    /// <para>Field Type: Single-Line Text</para>       
    /// <para>Field ID: 462e2170-1157-4e9d-92dc-0d5da2956c44</para>
    /// <para>Custom Data: </para>
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Team Development for Sitecore - GlassItem.tt", "1.0")]
    [SitecoreField(IMetadataConstants.PageTitleFieldName)]
    public virtual string PageTitle  {get; set;}                        
}
```

Comment: Which Glass MVC nuget package did you install?

Comment: Glass.Mapper version="3.0.13.25" 
Glass.Mapper.Sc version="3.2.2.44" 
Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor version="3.2.1.21" 
Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5 version="3.2.1.42"

Comment: hey @MichaelEdwards can you confirm if this is an issue on this version of glass?

Comment: I have been using Glass with 7.5 without issue.

Comment: Can you send me the view and the model to mike @ glass.lu?

Comment: @MichaelEdwards sent

Comment: I think I've found the issue. Sitecore 7.5 comes with MVC 5.1 libraries but when I created the MVC project in visual studio, the libraries are 5.2. I updated all project references to use 5.1 and the error dissapeared. PS: Make sure the web.config inside the views folder also points to 5.1

Comment: Glad you found the problem, that is a very annoying problem to have.