# Sitecore 8 Editable fields with Glass Mapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

For some reason Visual Studio Gives me this error in the view:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>' because it is not a delegate
>   type

Also, I do not have intellisense on the lambda.

I made sure to knock my MVC version down to 5.1.0 based on this post:

[Sitecore glass editable cannot convert lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26578805/sitecore-glass-editable-cannot-convert-lambda-expression)

Unfortunately, I didnt have the Stack Overflow points needed to comment directly on that post. Double unfortunately, the MVC version solution did not work for me. When I publish to deploy, the data comes through just fine - the editing works just fine - but I'd rather not just ignore red squiggly lines and lack of intellisense.

From a fresh Sitecore 8/Visual Studio MVC Application setup, I Ran:

Update-Package Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor to give me v3.3.1.26

Then I ran Install-Package Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc-5 to give me v3.3.1.48

**I set up a Model**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;

namespace myns.app.Models
{
    [SitecoreType]
    public class BaseContent
    {
        [SitecoreId]
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField("Content Title")]
        public virtual string Title { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField("Summary Content")]
        public virtual string Summary { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField("Full Content")]
        public virtual string Content { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField("Content Image")]
        public virtual Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Image ImagePath { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**And have a sort-of working view**

```xml
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<myns.app.Models.BaseContent>

<div>
    <h4>BaseContent</h4>
    <hr />
    @Model.Title
    <p>@Editable(Model, x => x.Title)</p>
    <p>@Editable(Model, x => x.Summary)</p>
    <h5>content</h5>
    <p>@Editable(Model, x => x.Content)</p>
    <p>@RenderImage(Model, x => x.ImagePath)</p> 
</div>
```

Thanks in advance to any input!

**UPDATE**:
When I comment out the following three lines in the **compilation>assemblies** in the web.config Sitecore provides, the problem seems to go away. Not sure this is the best thing to do:

```xml
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <!--add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
        <!--add assembly="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
        <!--add assembly="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenting out the following three lines in the assemblies node within the site's web.config fixed the problem.

```
<!--add assembly="System.Web.Http, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
<!--add assembly="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
<!--add assembly="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" /-->
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a discrepency in the versions of MVC your using. Check **all** your web.config (especially the one in the views folder) and make sure they're all using the same version of MVC. Later version of Visual studio also add a default layout this can break the intellisense when using sitecore.MVC.dll

Answer (score 0):

A quick test for me shows that there are no problems. I am using the latest Glass releases for all assemblies. Ensure that you have the correct assembly binding redirects in both the web.config and /views/web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I appreciate you chiming in.  I gave that a try - no dice (even after build and restart), However, I narrowed things down. I edited my post to show the three lines of the web.config that seem to cause it. Any thought on the right way to handle that (instead of commenting them out)?